Macro became very slow after Filter function
I have a worksheet with 30:31 pages for the month days and I have a Macro to add a symbol @ in the string between the two different lagnuages and it was working perfectly till I created a FILTER function in each page first row like this FILTER(E:F,G:G=D1041,"") then the macro became very slow I don't know why it even became very slow when i paste any text into the sheet. maybe it trys to check all the pages below my current page that I work on - .... please help
Sub englishATarabic()
    Dim L, count As Long, B, E As Range
    For R = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set B = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & R)
        Set E = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & R)
        If E.Value <> "" And B.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(B.Value) Then
            If InStr(E.Text, "@") < 1 Then
                count = 0
                For L = 1 To Len(E.Text)
                    If AscW(Mid(E.Text, L, 1)) < 1000 Then count = count + 1 Else Exit For
                Next
                
                E.Value = Left(E.Value, count) & "@" & Right(E.Value, Len(E.Value) - count)
                                                                           
            End If
        End If
    Next
                     
        ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub


Thousands of questions and answers about this here on SO: What slows down VBA is the interface with Excel. It's way faster to read all relevant data into memory in one go, handle the logic with the data in memory and write back everything again in one go.
Your code could look like this:
Sub englishATarabic()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim BData, EData
        Dim rowCount As Long
        rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).row
        BData = .Range("B1:B" & rowCount).Formula
        EData = .Range("E1:E" & rowCount).Formula
        
        Dim row As Long
        For row = 1 To UBound(BData)
            Dim eVal As Variant, bVal As Variant
            bVal = BData(row, 1)
            eVal = EData(row, 1)
                        
            If bVal <> "" And eVal <> "" And IsNumeric(bVal) Then
                Dim count As Long, l As Long
                If InStr(eVal, "@") < 1 Then
                    count = 0
                    For l = 1 To Len(eVal)
                        If AscW(Mid(eVal, l, 1)) < 1000 Then
                            count = count + 1
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
    
                    EData(row, 1) = Left(eVal, count) & "@" & Right(eVal, Len(eVal) - count)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        .Range("E1:E" & rowCount).Formula = EData
    End With
End Sub


thank you so much I was surprized that your edit run smoothly but unfortunately I dont know why it removes all the formulas from all the sheet in colunms C & D  also the FILTER function that i added in "E" even i added the formulas back but they disappear once I run the code...

Sorry, I completely forgot about formulas. I have changed the code, now the data of column B and E are written into 2 separate arrays (remember that even if they contain only one column of data, they are 2-dimensional arrays). As you modify only data of column E, only the array of column E is written back.

thank you sooo much I really do appreciate your help - it works perfectly  and faster but there is one simple issue .. after I run the Macro it gives me error message 400 - can you fix it please and please to make it save the workbook after run?

really thank you so much the new edit code is very very fast and running perfectly just please try to fix this 400 error .. if this can help, I don't have any formulas in "B" but formulas starts from "C" . also I tryed to change the vba option to (Break on all errors) and run the code it highlighted the last line in the code .Range("E1:E" & rowCount).Formula = EData

Sorry, but I can't fix that error. The code itself is working without errors, just tested it again. If you google around: The error 400 is kind of infamous and it's hard to find any reason for it. Maybe try to create a test workbook from scratch, copy over the data from your current sheet and run the code against that. Honestly, I have no clue how I could help you.

Use Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual in the beginning of your code and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic by the end.
Filter function is recalculated when you change your cell contents.
Sub englishATarabic()
    Dim L, count As Long, B, E As Range
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For R = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set B = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & R)
        Set E = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & R)
        If E.Value <> "" And B.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(B.Value) Then
            If InStr(E.Text, "@") < 1 Then
                count = 0
                For L = 1 To Len(E.Text)
                    If AscW(Mid(E.Text, L, 1)) < 1000 Then count = count + 1 Else Exit For
                Next
                
                E.Value = Left(E.Value, count) & "@" & Right(E.Value, Len(E.Value) - count)
                                                                           
            End If
        End If
    Next
                     
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub


can you please edit my code with that because I'm not expert in Vba

thank you so much I have tested your edit its's somehow better but unfortuately still very slow
